# how to get additional information by clicking a data point on bubble chart from data

Tags: highcharts

I am using this https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bubble-3d. And what I want is I can get some additional information about each data point from the data. I don't want to add alert to the data point. As I see most of the examples here were about to set alerts and getting information about respective point. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Highcharts [annotations](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations) to show additional information when a point is clicked.

Code:

```
  series: [{
    data: [{
      x: 1,
      y: 93,
      z: 55,
      yourProperty: 'Special bubble!'
    }]
  }],
  plotOptions: {
    bubble: {
      point: {
        events: {
          click: function() {
            var point = this,
              series = point.series,
              chart = series.chart,
              annotation;

            if (point.yourProperty) {
              annotation = chart.addAnnotation({
                labels: [{
                  point: point.id,
                  text: point.yourProperty
                }],
                labelOptions: {
                  align: 'right',
                  allowOverlap: true
                }
              });

              setTimeout(function() {
                chart.removeAnnotation(annotation.id);
              }, 2000);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z7jvben9/1/

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I am getting data from external csv file and with each data point I want add some terms(those are not the part of the chart plotting), which will show up only after clicking that bubble. Thanks again.

Comment: Could you prepare a simplified online demo of your chart with sample data and those terms?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. But I figured out with this example https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-ajax/. I am working on getting topics (another column from my data) to just get on this clickable windows. Thank you again.